# If iOS's filesystem is case-sensitive then why can't I save a.pages and A.pages?

Tags: ios, filesystem

When I try to save document in Pages.app on iOS with the same name but a different case I get:

```
"a" is already taken. Please choose a different name.
```

I would expect that this would work if iOS is case-sensitive.

Comment: I'd have to say with that error message, under the circumstances, it's obviously not case sensitive.

Comment: is it set to save/handoff over iCloud to a Mac? That might make it double-check for compatibility, as the Mac isn't case-sensitive by default. You're right that iOS **is** natively HFSX

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121210/how-can-i-read-write-and-check-case-insensitive-filenames-in-ios

Answer (score 2):

HFS+ is not case-sensitive.  It is, however, case-preserving.

Your problem is not a problem, it is working as designed.

Comment: The iOS file system is case-sensitive- HFSX .

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out recently, that even tho the iOS (iPhone/iPad) file system is case-sensitive, the iCloud storage IS NOT.

So if you could directly store to your iOS device, and not "hit" the iCloud storage you probably would be able to create the file(name).